# How do you enable newline seperation when writing multiple strings at once in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an incredibly basic Python 3 program that works fine. All it does is take from user input a string and a number. It then prints the string that number of times.

```
program1 = 25
print("[Type anything!]")
while program1 == 25:
        pcmd = input()
        amount = input("How many lines?: ")
        if amount.isnumeric():
            print(pcmd * int(amount))
        elif pcmd or amount == "exit":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid amount")
```

The thing is, whenever I run it and put in a string and amount, it prints all those strings next to each other.

Before, when I had statically defined strings, I could just use `'\n'` to make a newline. How can I do the same thing in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.

The simplest is to add a newline to the end of each string, like so:

```
print((pcmd + '\n') * int(amount))
```

You could use f-strings (Python >= 3.6 only) to achieve the same result:

```
print(f'{pcmd}\n' * int(amount))
```

You could use a `for` loop, since Python, by default, inserts a newline after every `print` call:

```
for i in range(int(amount)):
    print(pcmd)
```

You could collect the `pcmd` copies in a `list` and use unpacking, along with specifying a newline separator (though I don't recommend this - wasteful):

```
pcmd_copies = [pcmd for i in range(int(amount))]

print(*pcmd_copies, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Nice, I always hated that TOOWTDI nonsense :P Same as the last idea, but less wasteful: `print(*(pcmd for _ in range(amount)), sep="\n")`. And one more: `print("\n".join([pcmd] * amount))`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
print(pcmd * int(amount))
```

to

```py
print((pcmd +"\n" )* int(amount))
```